# Storing multiple variable via a single db call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- update: i need the results to be associated with the variables, and obviously maintaining order.

Hi folks, i find myself doing some variant of this often.

Essentially, i am doing 3 db calls, but I would like to do it in one single database call (for obvious performance reasons)

```
user1=User.find(x)
user2=User.find(y)
user3=User.find(z)
```

I believe there should be a simple rails method to handle this

I am using mongoid, but activerecord centric answers appreciated as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users = User.find(1,2,3)

User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to store the result in the variables:

```
user1, user2, user3 = User.find(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`users = User.find(x, y, z)` will return an array with your results.

Documentation:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

> Person.find(1, 2, 6) # returns an array for objects with IDs in (1, 2, 6)